# How can I remove the last 4 characters from a string?

Tags: string, go

I want to remove the last 4 characters from a string, so "test.txt" becomes "test".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    file := "test.txt"
    fmt.Print(strings.TrimSuffix(file, "."))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will safely remove any dot-extension - and will be tolerant if no extension is found:

```
func removeExtension(fpath string) string {
        ext := filepath.Ext(fpath)
        return strings.TrimSuffix(fpath, ext)
}
```

Playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/SEHl74QHhmy).

Table tests:

```
/www/main.js                             -> '/www/main'
/tmp/test.txt                            -> '/tmp/test'
/tmp/test2.text                          -> '/tmp/test2'
/tmp/test3.verylongext                   -> '/tmp/test3'
/user/bob.smith/has.many.dots.exe        -> '/user/bob.smith/has.many.dots'
/tmp/zeroext.                            -> '/tmp/zeroext'
/tmp/noext                               -> '/tmp/noext'
                                         -> ''
```

Answer (score 4):

Though there is already an accepted answer, I want to share some slice tricks for string manipulation.

1. **Remove last n characters from a string**

   As the title says, `remove the last 4 characters from a string`, it is very common usage of `slices`, ie,

   ```
   file := "test.txt"
   fmt.Println(file[:len(file)-4]) // you can replace 4 with any n
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   test
   ```

   Playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/Cnqr5oUFCkD).
2. **Remove file extensions:**

   From your problem description, it looks like you are trying to trim the file extension suffix (ie, `.txt`) from the string.

   For this, I would prefer @colminator's answer from above, which is

   ```
   file := "test.txt"
   fmt.Println(strings.TrimSuffix(file, filepath.Ext(file)))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove everything after last "."
[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Agak4g66pfb)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    sampleInput := []string{
    "/www/main.js",
    "/tmp/test.txt",
    "/tmp/test2.text",
    "/tmp/test3.verylongext",
    "/user/bob.smith/has.many.dots.exe",
    "/tmp/zeroext.",
    "/tmp/noext",
    "",
    "tldr",
    }
    for _, str := range sampleInput {
        fmt.Println(removeExtn(str))
    }
}

func removeExtn(input string) string {
    if len(input) > 0 {
        if i := strings.LastIndex(input, "."); i > 0 {
            input = input[:i]
        }
    }
    return input
}
```

Comment: Remember to check if the character exists in the string at all. Additionally a dot can also occur in directory names so if you are checking a path and not a filename this code should be adjusted.

Comment: this will `panic` your program with files without a dot: https://play.golang.org/p/EZit4VT16OU